# when declare iterator on global variable, not execute in my method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In the past, my app is record app 
I use `ArrayList` ,but ArrayList occur memory leak

```
`private ArrayList<OutputInputPair>> pairs = new ArrayList<OutPutInputPair>();`
```

so, when I click record stop button execute `pairs.clear();` `pairs = null;`

but if user never click record stop button. always occur memory leak.

so I use `WeakHashMap` in reference this site

[ArrayList<WeakReference<Runnable>> - How to tidy up best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589581/arraylistweakreferencerunnable-how-to-tidy-up-best)

in the past, I declare on global variable

`private ArraytList<OutputInputPair> pairs = new ArrayList<OutputInputPair>();`

I changed

`private WeakHaspMap<OutputInputPair, Void> pairs = new WeahHashMap<OutputInputPair, Void>();`

and `Iterator<OutputInputPair> iterator = pairs.keySet().iterator();` declare on global variable

According to my plan, execute my method. 
but if I declare `WeakHashMap` on global variable not execute my method.

my method source

```
public void process() {
     while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         OutputInputPair pair = iterator.next();
         //data insert on queue
     }
     while (!stopped) { //when I click record stop button, stopped is true 
         while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            OutputInputPair pair = iterator.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "<<<<<process>>>>"); //not show this log
            recordstart(pair);
         }
     }
   }
```

but if write `Iterator<OutputInputPair> iterator = pairs.keySet().iterator();`on my method, execute my method.

```
@Override
public void process() {
  Iterator<OutputInputPair> iterator = pairs.keySet().iterator(); // 
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         OutputInputPair pair = iterator.next();
         //data insert on queue
     }
     while (!stopped) { //when I click record stop button, stopped is true 
         while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            OutputInputPair pair = iterator.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "<<<<<process>>>>"); //not show this log
            recordstart(pair);
         }
     }
  }
```

this source execute my method.

in other words,why add 'Iterator iterator = pairs.keySet().iterator();` on global variable, not execute my method?

Why I want to be a global variable, if I add in my method, It runs indefinitely. because `while(!stopped)` .

please help me
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing more context to your code, but if you look at the docs for [`HashMap.keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) it reads

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined.

So if you initialize an iterator over the keySet in a static variable (what you're calling "global" I guess), and then some other part of your code modifies the entries in the hash map, it could have unpredictable results.